# How to properly write a vuepress plugin?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuepress

I am trying to write a Vuepress plugin to make use of App Level enhancement and install a Vue plugin. But I can't seem to get this to work. Can you please take a look at the code below and see what is wrong?

---

```
{.vuepress/config.js}
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('./builder.plugin.js')
  ]
}
```

---

```
{.vuepress/builder.plugin.js}
module.exports = (option, ctx) => {
  return {
    enhanceAppFiles: [{
      name: 'builder-plugin',
      content: `export default ({ Vue }) => {
        Vue.component('b-header', {
          name: 'b-header',
          template: '<div id="header"><slot /></div>'
        })
      }`
    }]
  }
}
```

---

```
{README.md}
# Introduction
<b-header>Test from component</b-header>
```

The final error I get is:

```
Unknown custom element: <b-header> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually found the answer. The above did not work because I was mixing client site code with runtime code by using a plugin.

The trick was to use enhanceAPP hook.
ref: https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/basic-config.html#theme-configuration

Comment: Good stuff. If anyone stumbles here, here's a good starting point for writing a plugin for VuePress - https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/tree/master/packages/docs/docs/plugin